# Shared Resource for Guest in SP Online Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm creating 100's of sites in our SP Online Tenant for client extranets.

I'm wondering if anyone has thoughts on a best practice for where to put shared assets like images and pdf files that you want any guest to have permissions as long as they are into any tenant site

Was thinking of using /Apps/SiteAssets since everyone has to have permissions to our custom web part from there.  But seeing if anyone had a better idea.

Comment: Do you want to share resources with anyone including external users or only users in your organization?

Comment: all authenticated users, including external users.